# Google autocomplete in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-2

I am having problem with google autocomplete in Angular.

The structure is index.html with

I have one page which is shown in ng-view - road.html.

Road.html

```
<input id="locationFrom"  type="text" class="form-control"/>
```

Road controller:

```
 app.controller("roadMapController", function () {
 var input = document.getElementById("locationFrom");

        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
}
```

I have no errors in console and input gets extra placeholder "Write locations...", but when I am typing there is are no hints like it should be.

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

First add the dependency to your app:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['google.places']);
```

After

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('locationFrom');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['establishment']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```